# No exception when unable to connect to kafka cluster

Tags: c#, error-handling, .net-core, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am unable get an exception when the program fails to connect to the kafka cluster.
The code outputs the exception in the console logs but I need it throw an exception. I am using this c# library:
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet

```
ProducerConfig _configKafka = new ProducerConfig { BootstrapServers ="localhost:9092/" };

ProducerBuilder<string, string> _kafkaProducer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(_configKafka);
using (var kafkaProducer = _kafkaProducer.Build())
{

    try
    {
        var dr = kafkaProducer.ProduceAsync("Kafka_Messages", new Message<string, string> { Key = null, Value = $"message {i++}" });
        dr.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        if(dr.Exception!=null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Delivery failed:");
        }

        var status = dr.Status;

        //Console.WriteLine($"Delivered '{dr.Value}' to '{dr.TopicPartitionOffset}'");
    }

    catch (ProduceException<Null, string> e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Delivery failed: {e.Error.Reason}");
    }
}
```

Below is the error printed by confluent-kafka in console:

```
%3|1565248275.024|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhst:9092/bootstrap]: localhst:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'localhst:9092': No such host is known.  (after 2269ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1565248275.024|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhst:9092/bootstrap]: localhst:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'localhst:9092': No such host is known.  (after 2269ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1565248275.025|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhst:9092/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the actual exception within your application you need to add `.SetErrorHandler()`:

```
    ProducerBuilder<string, string> _kafkaProducer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(_configKafka);

    using (var kafkaProducer = _kafkaProducer.SetErrorHandler((producer, error) =>
                        {
                           //You can handle error right here

                        }).Build())
```

*error.Reason* contains the error message

Comment: Thanks Olegl! It works. However, there will be 3 or more error handled. But I just want to get 1 error or exception once produce a message. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks Olegl, how do I come out of SetErrorHandler ?, I am trying to throw new Exception(error.Reason) but it won't come out of the loop and it is staying inside SetErrorHandler forever..

Answer (score 0):

You can use both **.SetLogHandler** and **.SetErrorHandler** in your consumer and producer code. Otherwise it kind of silently fails without providing much details. You can forward the messages to your logger there.